# How to connect a monitor to a Galaxy Tab tablet?

Tags: tablet, hdmi

I have a Galaxy Tab A (2018) and a Galaxy Tab S6 Lite tablets and I have to connect them to an external monitor with HDMI FullHD (1920 x 1080), how can I do that?

For example does it work with this adapter? - [QGeeM USB C to HDMI Adapter 4K Cable, USB Type-C to HDMI Adapter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07JW7GT7H)

What kind of frequencies does it support? My monitor works best at 75 Hz, at 60 Hz it doesn't use all the screen space, it leaves a border of 1-2 cm unused screen space on the border.

Comment: HDMI with more than 60 Hz is pretty unusual. I don't think that this is possible on HDMI versions prior to 2.0. As the linked adapter only supports 4k at 30 Hz it can't be a HDMI 2.0 device, HDMi 1.4 would be my guess.

Comment: Few devices support USB video out (requires USB-C 3.0+, neither of your tabs have).

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to do what you're looking for with Chromecast.

You'll only need one for each monitor/tv you're trying to use.

It's wireless, which may be a good thing, but it won't be perfect.  I think it won't be too good for fast paced games.